# How to save array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, save, storage

I have a basic app that populates an array and displays it in a listview. When I close the app and reopen it the listview is empty, where would you save the array? I see a lot of posts on shared preferences but it seems to be a workaround to store an array in there, also cant find any android documentation on array storage? Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

My code as requested....

```
    public class ListView_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String>mylistarray = new ArrayList<>();

String tempdescr;
String tempname;
static final int ADD_NEW_ITEM = 1;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_);
        /*add the main toolbar and make some changes to format*/
        Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.toolbartitle);
        mToolbar.setSubtitle(R.string.toolbarsubtitle);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        mToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));



        final ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListView_Activity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.row_item_text_view, mylistarray);

        /*create array adapter and set to listview*/

        final ListView mylistview = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        mylistview.setAdapter(myadapter);
        mylistarray.add("Test");
        myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final FloatingActionButton additembutton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        additembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent additem = new Intent(ListView_Activity.this, Create_Item_Activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(additem, 1);
            }
        });




    }

    /*load options menu to toolbar*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*handle options menu click events*/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                //intent here to load settings activity//
                return true;
            case R.id.Feedback:
                Intent Feedbackemail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Feedbackemail.setType("text/email");
                Feedbackemail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"adam.e.garnham@gmail.com"});
                Feedbackemail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                Feedbackemail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Dear..."+"");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Feedbackemail,"Send Feedback"));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == ADD_NEW_ITEM){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                tempdescr = data.getStringExtra("tempdescr");
                tempname = data.getStringExtra("tempname");
                mylistarray.add(tempdescr);
                mylistarray.add(tempname);



            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast replacewithcode = Toast.makeText(ListView_Activity.this, "replace with code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                replacewithcode.show();
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Where do you get your array?

Comment: The array is created in mainactivity and populated via a standard intent, will post code if you need it?

Comment: But if the array is created in main activity usually it should be created again if you close and reopen the app. Can you post your code for the activity

Comment: now adding it....

Answer (score 1):

There are several options you can go with to store your array.

Option 1.

Shared Preferences, its quick and pretty simple to understand. As long as your array isn't to large this would probably be the best option. Here is the link to the shared preference guide.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

With this you would probably want to use something like GSON to convert your array into a string and then store the string.

Option 2.

Store in a local mysqlite database, this is a little more complex to understand but can hold a lot of data for your array. Here is a link to the android sqlite guide.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html

Option 3.

Use a database/server, this one would take the longest to setup but would allow the app to fetch the data. This option would require an internet connection to the database though.

I would recommend going with setting up an mysqlite database if you think that you could handle it but if your a beginner I would lean towards storing the array in shared preferences since it would be a lot less code to set up.

Comment: Jacob you are a top man thank you this is exactly what I needed to get me going, will start reading!

Comment: You can also store them in a file system using Java IO API. But I agree with Jacob that the most suitable way to store the list of strings is to store them in a database. Google released a new API for dealing with databases called Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html